# what does ellipsis mean in a Matlab function's argument list?

Tags: matlab

What is the ellipsis for in this Matlab statement?

```
frame = insertObjectAnnotation(frame, 'rectangle', ...
                bboxes, labels);
```

...I could not find in their online doc.

Comment: it means "continue on next line", like `\` in C strings

Comment: Surprised you couldn't find anything because it's the first Google result for "Matlab ellipsis"... Also, for future reference, `help punct` in your Command Window may be useful for other operators and symbols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html

> **Continue Long Statements on Multiple Lines**
>
> This example shows how to continue a statement to the next line using ellipsis (...).
>
> ```
> s = 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 ...
>   - 1/6 + 1/7 - 1/8 + 1/9;
> ```